# Update HTML H4 tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble changing the "text" between an HTML tag using jQuery. When someone clicks on a "radio button", the text should be updated in a certain HTML element. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="radio-line" id="radio-manager">
    <input type="radio" id="rad-400" name="radio-manager" value="No"  />
</div>
```

HTML to be updated on radio check:

```
<h4 class="manager">Manager</h4>
```

When someone clicks on the radio above, the "Manager" text should become "Employees". I tried some jQuery code but cannot quite figure it out.

Comment: what was the jQuery code you tried?

Comment: `$("h4.manager").text("Employees");` should do it. What have you tried?

Comment: @JasonTowne Thank you! this solved my problem...I was using the .html() function

Comment: @three3 Glad I could help. I posted my comment as an answer so you can mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check out the following fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/JBjXN/

```
<div class="radio-line" id="radio-manager">
    <input type="radio" id="rad-400" name="radio-manager" value="No" data-text="Employees" />
</div>

<h4 class="manager">Manager</h4>

$('.radio-line').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', changeText);

function changeText(e) {
    $('.manager').text($(e.currentTarget).data('text'));
}​
```

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do is this -

```
$('input[name="radio-manager"]').change(function() {
    if($('#rad-400').is(':checked')){
        $('h4.manager').text('Employees');
    } else {
        $('h4.manager').text('Manager');
    }
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Eub9Y/

Answer (score 3):

From my comment above:

```
$("h4.manager").text("Employees");
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
$("#rad-400").on("click", function () {
    $(".manager").text("Employees");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$("#rad-r00").click(function() {
    if ($('input:radio[name=radio-manager]:checked').val() == "Yes") {
        $(".manager").html('Manager')
    }
    else {
        $(".manager").html('Not - Manager');
    }
 });
```